# Не получается стартовать Python Windows службу под пользователем

Tags: python, windows-service

Windows служба на питоне нормально стартует под служебной учетной записью.
Но не запускается под пользователем. Ошибка 1053
Раньше этот же сервис успешно работал под этим же пользователем. Пользователь с правами администратора (моя учетная запись).
Для отладки взял из инета пустой сервис без всякой логики. Результат тот же.

Отличие от предыдущих запусков в том что Python установлен глобально и в том что версия питона 39 (была 38)

Comment: http://self-it.ru/windows/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/ - это, конечно, "грязный хак" , но все же.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Что вам нужно сделать, так это добавить Python в **SYSTEM PATH**, а не в **USER PATH**, поскольку по умолчанию служба python будет установлена ​​как `` LocalSystem '', и поэтому при попытке запуска она использует переменную SYSTEM PATH - это почему вы можете запустить его из командной строки, ваш ПУТЬ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ правильный.

По умолчанию python устанавливается как LocalSystem, который настроен с использованием пользовательских путей вместо переменных среды, поэтому вам необходимо добавить переменные среды.

Удалите путь python из пользовательской переменной и добавьте путь python к переменной среды.

C: \ Users \ user_name \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Lib \ site-packages \ pywin32_system32;

C: \ Users \ user_name \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Lib \ site-packages \ win32 ；

C: \ Users \ user_name \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Scripts ;

C: \ Users \ zhongjianhui \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python36\

Запуск службы выполнен успешно.

Comment: Удалил питон и поставил заново уже локально. Прописал указанные пути.  К сожалению не заработало.

Comment: Ты сделал все точно как я написал????

Comment: просто эта ошибка именно то что я написал означает....

Comment: у вас были ранее установленые версии питона

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????

Comment: @Alexalexeev во-первых, не надо гегенировать комментарии каждую секунду. Это не чат, автор вопроса может не читать ваши комментарии в реальном времени. Во-вторых, эта ошибка означает совсем не то, что вы написали.

Comment: @stawdog Если ты знаешь что она означает то напиши ответ мой хороший)

Comment: @user2749279 нашёл еще на stackoverflow возможное решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466053/all-python-windows-service-can-not-starterror-1053

Comment: @user2749279 можно ошибку полностью???

Comment: @strawdog ясно слита

Comment: Что значит полностью. я пробую запустить службу она не запускается и показывается сообщение Не удалось запустить службу тест на локальный компьютер. Ошибка 1053:Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.

Comment: Инсталлированный питон у меня один. Сейчас локально для пользователя. Пути прописаны в System Path именно туда. То есть я могу из под пользователя исполнить команду PIP например.

Comment: И копирование длл из pywin32_system32\ в win32\ то же не помогло.

Comment: @user2749279 дебаг мод врубал(any_service.py debug)?

Comment: Нет пока. Сейчас разберусь как это делать и попробую.

Comment: @user2749279 ну как? получилось?